# Read unique Char format in R

Tags: json, r

I have a data.frame `DT_A`, with several rows and two columns `address` and `date_time` (of class character). Example of rows:

```
 address             date_time
 Canada 1            '"verfied"=>"2013-07-28 09:47:20 +0000", "verified_oleh"=>"nur@web.com", "verfification req"=>"2013-04-21 05:22:00 +0000"'   
 Canada 1            '"verfied"=>"2013-07-28 09:47:20 +0000", "verfied_oleh"=>"nur@web.com"
 Germany             '"verfied"=>"2013-07-28 09:47:20 +0000", "verified_oleh"=>"nur@web.com", "verfification req"=>"2013-04-21 05:22:00 +0000"'   
 Germany             '"verfied"=>"2013-07-28 09:47:20 +0000", "verfied_oleh"=>"nur@web.com"'
```

The column `date_time` can take other status.

I need to filter each row of column `date_time` has "verified" string, I think it need to convert to JSON, I have tried to `jsonlite` package, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your post is a mess. Please edit to make it clearer.

Comment: i have edit my question, it is clear @Pascal ? thx

Comment: It is still not clear what is the content of column `date_time`.

Comment: content is status ==> datetimeformat,,,example  '"verfied"=>"2013-07-28 09:47:20 +0000", "verified_oleh"=>"nur@web.com", "verfification req"=>"2013-04-21 05:22:00 +0000"' 

or

 '"verfied"=>"2013-07-28 09:47:20 +0000", "verfied_oleh"=>"nur@web.com"'

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by "has "verified string". But if I assume that you mean that there is the string "verified" in your `date_time` column this should do the trick:

```
DT_A[grepl('^"verfied"', DT_A$date_time, ] # please note the typo in verfied
```

This `grepl` looks for the regular expression where the string starts with "verfied".

Comment: hei thx,,,but i try it's.. DT_pesan_kpn[grep('^"verified", DT_pesan_kpn$date_time)] it's not work .__.

Comment: did you miss the `,` after grep?

Comment: hi @thothal ,,, it's can't be execute,,,format of grep is correct from you ? because it's look like not complete....

Comment: Gosh, I missed the ' in my post, it is fixed now. Can you try again?